# C# List<string>[] to Datatable

Tags: c#, list, datatable

I need to convert a list array of type **`List<string>[]`** to Datatable in C#.

I have found many topics related to **`List<string[]>`** to Datatable conversion but nothing on the conversion I need.

Pseudocode:

```
//Retrieve data from MySQL server 
db.Select(category, productID);
//populate List<string>[] array 
list[0] = db.ListQuery[0];
list[1] = db.ListQuery[1];

//convert list[] to Datatable
.....
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What are "conversion" rules? Besides, you don't want a conversion. You want to fill `DataTable` with the data from `List<string[]>`.

Comment: @Dennis'list<string>[]' is different from 'list<string[]>'. I mentioned that on the title and bold it... Any way, I solve the issue by using 'MySQLDataAdapter' instead of 'MySQLDataReader' and filled a table directly.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question right, do you mean something like this?

```
string category = "Category";
string productId = "ProductId";
List<string[]> tempList = db.Select(category, productID); //Not necessarily correct (I'm not familiar with MySQL). Do what you need to do to create the List<string[]>
DataTable table = new DataTable();
DataRow row;
table.Columns.Add(category);
table.Columns.Add(productId);
foreach (string[] s in tempList)
{
   row = table.NewRow();
   row[category] = s[0];
   row[productId] = s[1];
   table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            List<MemberInfo> props = typeof(T).GetFields().Select(objField => (MemberInfo)objField).ToList();
            props.AddRange(typeof(T).GetProperties().Select(objField => (MemberInfo)objField));

            if (props.Count > 0)
            {
                Type t;
                bool tIsField = false;
                for (int iCnt = 0; iCnt < props.Count; iCnt++)
                {
                    var prop = props[iCnt];
                    tIsField = prop.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field;
                    dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, tIsField ? ((FieldInfo)prop).FieldType : ((PropertyInfo)prop).PropertyType);
                }
                foreach (T item in data)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dataTable.NewRow();

                    foreach (var field in props)
                    {
                        tIsField = field.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field;
                        object value = tIsField ? ((FieldInfo)field).GetValue(item) : ((PropertyInfo)field).GetValue(item, null);
                        dr[field.Name] = value;
                    }
                    dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }
            return dataTable;
```